# print the unique values in every column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, for-loop, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) and want to print the unique values from each column in the dataframe.

I need to substitute the variable (i) [column name] into the print statement

```
column_list = df.columns.values.tolist()
for column_name in column_list:
    print(df."[column_name]".unique()
```

**Update**

When I use this: I get **"Unexpected EOF Parsing"** with no extra details.

```
column_list = sorted_data.columns.values.tolist()
for column_name in column_list:
      print(sorted_data[column_name].unique()
```

What is the difference between your syntax YS-L (above) and the below:

```
for column_name in sorted_data:
      print(column_name)
      s = sorted_data[column_name].unique()
      for i in s:
        print(str(i))
```

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis in your print statement, that's what causes the error.

Answer (score 126):

It can be written more concisely like this:

```
for col in df:
    print(df[col].unique())
```

Generally, you can access a column of the DataFrame through [indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#basics) using the `[]` operator (e.g. `df['col']`), or through [attribute](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access) (e.g. `df.col`).

Attribute accessing makes the code a bit more concise when the target column name is known beforehand, but has several caveats -- for example, it does not work when the column name is not a valid Python identifier (e.g. `df.123`), or clashes with the built-in DataFrame attribute (e.g. `df.index`). On the other hand, the `[]` notation should always work.

Comment: Ah fantastic, so when referencing a variable which is part of a datagrams you don't include the dot before df.col-name when the column is a variable?!

Comment: @yoshiserry: Generally you either access a column using dot notation: `df.my_col`, *or* indexing notation, with the column name as a string: `df['my_col']`. You seem to be mixing up the two a bit.

Comment: Thanks Marius, when I use indexing notation I am getting a syntax error (see edit).

Comment: YS-L I get a syntax error when I write this, which just says "invalid syntax" and no specifics. However does this mean the same principle could be used to split a large dataframe into multiple smaller dataframes (one for every month of the year?).  

month = df.month.unique().tolist()
for item in month:
    [item] = df[df[month]==[item]]

Comment: For the error, please add it into your question so we may help. For the second part, you are probably looking for something like [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) (please open another question for that if necessary instead of discussing here :-).

Comment: No I am looking to create multiple separate dataframes, not use (groupby). In addition to referring to the df I create on import i'd like to be able to refer to only a month of data at a time, (thus why I want a separate dataframe for Jan, Feb, Mar etc).

Answer (score 25):

Most upvoted answer is a loop solution, hence adding a one line solution using pandas apply() method and lambda function.

```
print(df.apply(lambda col: col.unique()))
```

Comment: The question is asking for the unique values, not the number of unique values, so just a matter of changing the applied function: 
print(df.apply(lambda col: col.unique()))

Comment: when I do this I get the error message `arrays must be the same length`. All columns have the same amount or rows so why would I get that message?

Comment: And to get the values printed out a bit nicer (at least in my opinion) could add something like `df.apply(lambda col: ', '.join(map(str, col.unique())))`

Answer (score 12):

This will get the unique values in proper format:

```
pd.Series({col:df[col].unique() for col in df})
```

Comment: Short and precise.

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to create multiple separate dataframes as mentioned in your comments, create a dictionary of dataframes:

```
df_dict = dict(zip([i for i in df.columns] , [pd.DataFrame(df[i].unique(), columns=[i]) for i in df.columns]))
```

Then you can access any dataframe easily using the name of the column:

```
df_dict[column name]
```

Answer (score 4):

We can make this even more concise:

```
df.describe(include='all').loc['unique', :]
```

Pandas describe gives a few key statistics about each column, but we can just grab the 'unique' statistic and leave it at that.

Note that this will give a unique count of `NaN` for numeric columns - if you want to include those columns as well, you can do something like this:

```
df.astype('object').describe(include='all').loc['unique', :]
```

Comment: This also gives the number of unique values, not the unique values themselves. Btw, the num of unique values is even easier to get like `df.nunique()`

Answer (score 4):

I was seeking for a solution to this problem as well, and the code below proved to be more helpful in my situation,

```
for col in df:
    print(col)
    print(df[col].unique())
    print('\n')
```

It gives something like below:

```
Fuel_Type
['Diesel' 'Petrol' 'CNG']


HP
[ 90 192  69 110  97  71 116  98  86  72 107  73]


Met_Color
[1 0]
```

Comment: this was helpful in my case as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code below could provide you a list of unique values for each field, I find it very useful when you want to take a deeper look at the data frame:

```
for col in list(df):
    print(col)
    print(df[col].unique())
```

You can also sort the unique values if you want them to be sorted:

```
import numpy as np
for col in list(df):
    print(col)
    print(np.sort(df[col].unique()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cu = []
i = []
for cn in card.columns[:7]:
    cu.append(card[cn].unique())
    i.append(cn)

pd.DataFrame( cu, index=i).T
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    print(df[i].unique())
```

Answer (score 0):

Or in short it can be written as:

```
for val in df['column_name'].unique():
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better. Here's code to view all the unique values as a dataframe column-wise transposed:

```
columns=[*df.columns]
unique_values={}
for i in columns:
    unique_values[i]=df[i].unique()
unique=pd.DataFrame(dict([ (k,pd.Series(v)) for k,v in unique_vals.items() ]))
unique.fillna('').T
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution constructs a dataframe of unique values with some stats and gracefully handles any unhashable column types.

Resulting dataframe columns are: `col`, `unique_len`, `df_len`, `perc_unique`, `unique_values`

```py
df_len = len(df)
unique_cols_list = []
for col in df:
    try:
        unique_values = df[col].unique()
        unique_len = len(unique_values)
    except TypeError:  # not all cols are hashable
        unique_values = ""
        unique_len = -1
    perc_unique = unique_len*100/df_len
    unique_cols_list.append((col, unique_len, df_len, perc_unique, unique_values))
df_unique_cols = pd.DataFrame(unique_cols_list, columns=["col", "unique_len", "df_len", "perc_unique", "unique_values"])
df_unique_cols = df_unique_cols[df_unique_cols["unique_len"] > 0].sort_values("unique_len", ascending=False)
print(df_unique_cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pandas `apply()` method and pass a callable, np.unique in this case:

```
df.apply(np.unique)
```

Because you are using apply on an entire data frame (vs. individual columns/series), each column becomes the element or `x` which will receive the function

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging numpy

`np.unique(df.values)`

It gives unique elements in dataframe, iterate or just print array.

Answer (score -3):

The best way to do that:

```
Series.unique()
```

For example **students.age.unique()** the output will be the different values that occurred in the age column of the students' data frame.

To get only the number of how many different values:

```
Series.nunique()
```

Comment: This does not answer how to get the unique values from each column